# how to use the urlize filter on the templates' url function?

Tags: python, django, templates, url, urlize

In a Django template, I am trying to use the `urlize` filter just after the `url` function is being used, which is generating an url and subsequently generating its `<a>` tag.

Unfortunately various attempts of using `(url myview)|urlize` and similar experiments did not work. Any ideas on how to put the pieces together to make the thing work?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the url to a variable like so:

```
{% url "myview" as my_url %}
{{ my_url|urlize }}
```

You can also just use `{% filter %}` to accomplish the same without assigning first:

```
{% filter urlize %}{% url "myview" %}{% endfilter %}
```

With the poster above, it doesn't really make much sense to do any of this.  Why wouldn't you just create the hyperlink itself rather than rely on the filter to convert from a url to a hyperlink?

```
<a href="{% url "myview" %}">{% url "myview" %}</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not what `urlize` is for. It's for searching for URLs inside a block of text and converting them to clickable links. The result of the `{% url %}` doesn't even look like a link in that way, as it's a relative link (eg `/index/` rather than `www.example.com/index`), and the docs are pretty specific about what `urlize` looks for:

> This template tag works on links prefixed with `http://`, `https://`, or `www.`.

Not sure why you'd want it anyway: it's trivial to define the link yourself:

```
This is my link: <a href="{% url 'myview' %}">My view</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. Do you know any way to create the link automatically from a view's name? Because that's what I wanted, using the nice automatization of the urlize filter.